# Rotating (and resizing) 2D coordinate lists in Python

Tags: python, coordinates

I have several sequences of the following list of 2D coordinate pairs (which actually denote a path) in Python:

```
a = [[0, 0], [1, 0.4], [1.2, 0.6], [1.6, 0.9], [1.9, 2.1]]
b = [[-0.3, 0.5], [1.33, 0.46], [2.34, 0.6], [2.6, 1]]
c = [[10, 0.2], [10.1, 0.3], [10.2, 0.4], [11.6, 0.5], [13.9, 0.77]]
```

The lists differ in length, not each of them starts from [0, 0]

Now, I want to "normalize" them so that each of them start from `[0, 0]` and rotate they proportionally so that the final point be at the positive direction of the X axis `[+something, 0]`. How could I achieve this transformation so that the original proportions are kept?

Bonus question: how could I solve this so that the last point always be at `[1, 0]` so the path is not only rotated but resized as well?

Comment: This is really not a programming question, but a linear algebra question.

Comment: What did you try? The first step is kinda obvious

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first step is straightforward.

For the second, you can use [`atan2`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.atan2) to calculate the angle between the X axis and the last point. Apply a [rotation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#In_two_dimensions) of `-theta` to every point, and you're done.

It shouldn't be hard to write the 3rd function now.

```
from math import cos, sin, atan2

a = [[0, 0], [1, 0.4], [1.2, 0.6], [1.6, 0.9], [1.9, 2.1]]
b = [[-0.3, 0.5], [1.33, 0.46], [2.34, 0.6], [2.6, 1]]
c = [[10, 0.2], [10.1, 0.3], [10.2, 0.4], [11.6, 0.5], [13.9, 0.77]]

def move_to_origin(l):
    x0, y0 = l[0]
    return [(x - x0, y - y0) for x, y in l]

def rotate_to_x_axis(l):
    xn, yn = l[-1]
    theta = atan2(-yn, xn)
    return [(x*cos(theta) - y*sin(theta), x*sin(theta) + y*cos(theta)) for x, y in l]

print(move_to_origin(a))
# [(0, 0), (1, 0.4), (1.2, 0.6), (1.6, 0.9), (1.9, 2.1)]
print(move_to_origin(b))
# [(0.0, 0.0), (1.6300000000000001, -0.03999999999999998), (2.6399999999999997, 0.09999999999999998), (2.9, 0.5)]
print(move_to_origin(c))
# [(0, 0.0), (0.09999999999999964, 0.09999999999999998), (0.1999999999999993, 0.2), (1.5999999999999996, 0.3), (3.9000000000000004, 0.5700000000000001)]
print(rotate_to_x_axis(move_to_origin(a)))
# [(0.0, 0.0), (0.9675276356186346, -0.47317044953612064), (1.250017456237214, -0.4872949405670496), (1.740843519561996, -0.5826352550258203), (2.831960451701259, 0.0)]
```

Here's a small matplotlib graph with the steps for `b`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(*zip(*b))
plt.plot(*zip(*move_to_origin(b)))
plt.plot(*zip(*rotate_to_x_axis(move_to_origin(b))))
plt.gca().set_aspect('equal', adjustable='box')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. I wonder how could one tune further in order to squeeze (normalize) all coordinate values to 0-1 (or at least -1 - 1) range.

Comment: @Hendrik: What did you try? Which value do you need? How would you get it? The function wouldn't be much different that `move_to_origin`